# after reinstall geoserver how to locate old geoserver files

Tags: geoserver, cartography

i have published lots of Arch GIS map on Geo server software. but few days ago because of some problem in my system i have uninstalled Geo server 2.1.4 from my system. but i kept a copy of my Geo server folder. Now i have again installed the same version of Geo server in my system. now the question is how to relocate my work folder in Geo server. i don't want to publish again all those files.

Comment: You'll have to give us more information about your Configuration, like the OS that you are using, How are you installing it. These will determine how you set the data directory to the old folder.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/index.html and http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html#data-dir-setting it may help.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy folder "data" in geoserver(your backup) and replace it to(new) .war and "data" in geoserver folder
2. restart tomcat `/etc/init.d/tomacat7 restart`
3. change owner "data" on geoserver to  tomcat user

   `cd to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver`

   `sudo chown -R tomcat7 data`

   `sudo chown -R :tomcat7 data`
4. reload store on geoserver

Comment: sorry if my content is not beautiful